# How to solve floating point error when comparing two numbers

Tags: python

```
import math
from fractions import Fraction
Lis = [
       1, 2 , 3 , 6 , 1/2 , 1/3 , 1/4 , 1/6 , 1/12 , 2/3, 3/2, 3/4, 
       -1,-2,-3,-6, -1/2 , -1/3 , -1/4 , -1/6 , -1/12 , -2/3, -3/2, -3/4  
      ]
for x in lis:
    if abs((12(x^3) - 32 (x^2) + 25 (x) - 6 ) - 0) == 1*max (abs(12 (x)^3 - 32 (x^2) + 25 (x) - 6), abs (0)) == True :
        print(x, end = ', ')
```

I was trying to solve a polynomialfunction using a python but I faced a blessing; as a result, I make a list of possible zeros of the function, so next from that list, using the for loop, I tried to enter those numbers into the equation, but I find only two answers 1/2, and 3/2 on zeros was missed 3/2 because of its decimal repetition 0.6666667; as a result, this number doesn't give zero but 2/3 so my question is there any way I can rid of this problem and get an output of
1/2,2/3, and 3/2 ?

Comment: @Jordan--your code has errors: 1) `^` is bitwise xor operator, `**` is exponentiation, 2) You define `Lis` but your for loop has `for x in lis`. 3) You need a `*` between constants and variable to multiply i.e. `12*(x**3)` rather than 12(x)^3.  Also, it's not an error, but what's the point of abs(0) vs. simply using 0 (introduces confusion)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `math` package and with `isclose` instead of `==` you can solve. the problem, if you use python 3.5=< version

```
import math

math.isclose(1.656, 1655, abs_tol=0.001)
```

result is

```
True
```

if your version is 3.5> then you can define it as below:

```
def isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0):
    return abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)
```

so your target code will be as below:

```
import math
from fractions import Fraction
Lis = [
       1, 2 , 3 , 6 , 1/2 , 1/3 , 1/4 , 1/6 , 1/12 , 2/3, 3/2, 3/4,
       -1,-2,-3,-6, -1/2 , -1/3 , -1/4 , -1/6 , -1/12 , -2/3, -3/2, -3/4
      ]
for x in Lis:
    first_value = abs((12. * (x ^ 3) - 32. * (x ^ 2) + 25. * (x) - 6.) - 0)
    sec_value = 1 * max(abs(12. * (x ^ 3) - 32. * (x ^ 2) + 25. * x - 6.), abs(0))
    if math.isclose(first_value, sec_value, abs_tol=0.001):
        print(x, end=', ')
```

Comment: More about `isclose` can be found here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/

Comment: @MaryamAbdoli--this code produces error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

Issues with OP code

1. You import Fraction module but don't use it
2. ^ is bitwise xor operator, ** is exponentiation,
3. You define Lis but your for loop has for x in lis.
4. You need a * between constants and variable to multiply i.e. 12*(x**3) rather than 12(x)^3.

**Code**

```
import math
from fractions import Fraction
# Use Fraction for fractional numbers
Lis = [
       1, 2 , 3 , 6 , Fraction('1/2'), Fraction('1/3'), Fraction('1/4'), Fraction('1/6'), 
        Fraction('1/12'), Fraction('2/3'), Fraction('3/2'), Fraction('3/4'), 
       -1, -2, -3, -6, Fraction('-1/2'), Fraction('-1/3'), Fraction('-1/4'), 
        Fraction('-1/6'), Fraction('-1/12'), Fraction('-2/3'), Fraction('-3/2'), Fraction('-3/4') \
      ]
for x in Lis:
    value = 12*(x**3) - 32*(x**2) + 25*x - 6
    if value == 0:            # Now we can compare value to absolute 0 (since we use Fraction)
        print(x, end=', ')
```

**Output** (outputs fractions)

```
1/2, 2/3, 3/2,
```